# How to fix: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, redux

I'm making ReactApp, and when i try to write something in Input, i have this error, and i have no idea how to solve this... Can anybody help me? And also explaine me how to make rigth dispatch in this situation.

---

**API request**

```
export const searchWeather = value => {
    Axios.get(`${API.base}weather?q=${value}&units=metric&APPID=${API.key}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export const getCurrentWeather = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        let value = initialState.cityValue

        dispatch(loader(true))
        dispatch(searchWeather(value))
        dispatch(loader(false))
    } 
}
```

**Container**

```
class NavContainer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        getCurrentWeather()
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <NavBar {...this.props} />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    cityValue: state.weatherReducer.cityValue
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getCityValue,getCurrentWeather})(NavContainer)
```

**Component**

```
const NavBar = ({cityValue,getCityValue,getCurrentWeather}) => {

    return(
        <div className="row">
            <div className='col-lg-4 nav-bar-mobile' >
                <ul>
                    <li >Home</li>
                    <li>Weather</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className='col-lg-8 search-bar'>
                <input onKeyPress={getCurrentWeather} value={cityValue} onChange={e => getCityValue(e.target.value)} placeholder='Search Location...'/>
            </div>
            <div className='col-lg-4 nav-bar' >
                <ul>
                    <li >Home</li>
                    <li>Weather</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Redux alone doesn't handle asynchronous actions, it needs some middleware. Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk. Looks like you've also mixed up your action/reducer definitions, reducers are pure functions of shape `(state, action) => state`.

Comment: @DrewReese 1) I have istalled redux-thunk  2) I'm not totally understand what I mixed up.. I can add Reducer component if you need to see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some middleware, for example redux-thunk. You should create thunk looks like

```
const searchWeather = data => dispatch => {
    searchWeatherAxiosRequest(data)}
```

And then use this thunk in component on handle click:

```
 searchWeather()
```

Also you shouldn't dispatch something in Reducer. Reducer should just change the state